# Flash AS3 calling a function from a class within a seperate class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, function

I've been searching around trying to work this out for a while now. There's been various ideas popping up, like dispatchEvent etc but nothing that seems to be a clear, simple way of doing this.

What I'm trying to do is call a function from a class seperate (but in the same folder as) my document class.
Specifically, I want to 'spawn' an object and run a function within that object's class from my Main.as.
The snippet I have at the moment is as follows;

In Main.as:

```
var object:class_Object = new class_Object();
object.spawn();
addChild(object);
```

The spawn function is a public function within class_Object but when I try and run this, I get the error: 'Error #1006: spawn is not a function' 
If I take out the 'object.spawn();' code it adds the object fine.

I must be missing something obvious, but can't figure out what

Thanks

**EDIT**

Fixed the problem, I had forgotten to specify the path to the class in the AS linkage of my Library object, thought I'd done that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You marked that method as `static`. That means that it belongs to the *class* itself not *instances* of that class.

To invoke the method as defined you would say:

`class_Object.spawn()`

However, this may not be what is intended, but it's difficult to say without seeing the implementation. Removing the `static` keyword from its definition will attach it to an *instance* and will be accessible the way you have described.

See [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f30.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f25) for the adobe documentation on the subject.

---

To answer your comment, a simple way to think about it is a "class" is a blueprint to create "instances".

So, when you say `new class_Object()` you telling the "blueprint" to "construct" a new instance of the blueprint. In side the blueprint you can define methods/properties that should available to the instance (or instance methods). Also, you can also define methods/properties that are available to the "blueprint" itself (or static methods).

So using the classic example of a `Car`

```
public class Car {

    public function startEngine():void {
        // This is an instance method, it will be available to
        // any instance of a car, or new Car();

        // Note: "this" in this context refers to the current instance of the car
        // that the method is being called from
    }

    public static function compare(Car car1, Car car2):bool {
        // This method belongs to the blueprint of a car

        // Note: "this" doesn't make any sense in this context, because we 
        // aren't talking about a particular instance.
    }
}
```

Then for example:

```
var mercedes:Car = new Car();
var bmw:Car = new Car();

mercedes.startEngine(); // call an instance method. notice we call it from a particular instance of a car.
Car.compare(mercedes, bmw); // call an static method. notice we call it from the class of Car.
```

When you "extend" from another class, you are "borrowing" the functionality from another class and adding/replacing your own functionality. But as long as you have an instance, if it is a "public" method, then it will be externally available from where ever that instance is available. I don't know if that helps answer you comment.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't realise static attatched it purely to the class, thanks for clearing that up. However, they are two seperate classes, not instances of one, if I understand correctly anyway. So I have the Main class extending MovieClip and my Object class extending Sprite. This would only work if the Main file extended the object file? Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's definitely helpful, I have a better understanding of classes now, so thank you! However, I am initiating and calling an instance of my object class like you did above and calling a method from it like above, yet it throws the error. I'm not sure if it matters that I'm setting up the variable and calling the method from within an Enter_Frame function, shouldn't do. Oh and if I try and call a static method, like you did, I get the error: '1061: Call to possible undefined method 'method' through a reference with static type Class'  Thanks very much for your patience!

Comment: /facepalm! Man I'm an idiot. On the Library object that was linked to my class, I hadn't specified the path (com.X.Y.class), so it was getting very confused. It's all working now, so sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the method inside your class_Object public

```
package my.package{
    public class class_Object(){
         public function class_Object(){
             //constructor 
         }

         public function spawn():void{
               //spawn code
         }

    }
}



var classObject:class_Object = new class_Object();
classObject.spawn();
```