# TypeError: Error #1006: encode is not a function

Tags: flash, png, flash-cs5, filereference

I keep getting this error and it is driving me crazy.  This is the first time I've tried to export a `Flash MovieClip` into a downloadable `*.PNG` file.  I followed a guide online and implemented Adobe's `PNGEncoder.as` "image".

> Guide: http://permadi.com/blog/2011/02/flash-as3-saving-image-to-disk/
>   PNGEncoder:https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/tree/master/src/com/adobe/images/

I set up the `PNGEncoder.as` class and changed preferences so `Flash` would recognize it (this was confirmed).  Now when I run the `SWF` and click the button, it does nothing and OUTPUT says `TypeError: Error #1006: encode is not a function.`

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import customClasses.PNGEncoder;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

stop();

/*
CAMERA button command
Opens download command window to save instance of theBike as .PNG

*/

CAMERA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_20);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_20(event:MouseEvent):void
{
// source for the bitmap data in this case is a text field
var tf:MovieClip = Object(root).bike;

// create new transparent BitmapData object to hold the captured data
// BitmapData(width, height, transparent, color)
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(640, 406, true, 0x000000);

// draw the source data into the BitmapData object
myBitmapData.draw(tf);

// make a new Bitmap object and populate with the BitmapData object
var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapData);

var myPNG:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
var byteArray:ByteArray = myPNG.encode(myBitmapData); <-- PROBLEM HERE

var fileReference:FileReference=new FileReference();
fileReference.save(byteArray, "bike.png");
}
```

From PNGEncoder.as:

```
package customClasses
{
    import flash.geom.*;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

/**
 * Class that converts BitmapData into a valid PNG
 */ 
public class PNGEncoder
{
    /**
     * Created a PNG image from the specified BitmapData
     *
     * @param image The BitmapData that will be converted into the PNG format.
     * @return a ByteArray representing the PNG encoded image data.
     */         
    public static function encode(img:BitmapData):ByteArray {
        // Create output byte array
        var png:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        // Write PNG signature
        png.writeUnsignedInt(0x89504e47);
        png.writeUnsignedInt(0x0D0A1A0A);
        // Build IHDR chunk
        var IHDR:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        IHDR.writeInt(img.width);
        IHDR.writeInt(img.height);
        IHDR.writeUnsignedInt(0x08060000); // 32bit RGBA
        IHDR.writeByte(0);
        writeChunk(png,0x49484452,IHDR);
        // Build IDAT chunk
        var IDAT:ByteArray= new ByteArray();
        for(var i:int=0;i < img.height;i++) {
            // no filter
            IDAT.writeByte(0);
            var p:uint;
            var j:int;
            if ( !img.transparent ) {
                for(j=0;j < img.width;j++) {
                    p = img.getPixel(j,i);
                    IDAT.writeUnsignedInt(
                        uint(((p&0xFFFFFF) << 8)|0xFF));
                }
            } else {
                for(j=0;j < img.width;j++) {
                    p = img.getPixel32(j,i);
                    IDAT.writeUnsignedInt(
                        uint(((p&0xFFFFFF) << 8)|
                        (p>>>24)));
                }
            }
        }
        IDAT.compress();
        writeChunk(png,0x49444154,IDAT);
        // Build IEND chunk
        writeChunk(png,0x49454E44,null);
        // return PNG
        return png;
    }

    private static var crcTable:Array;
    private static var crcTableComputed:Boolean = false;

    private static function writeChunk(png:ByteArray, 
            type:uint, data:ByteArray):void {
        if (!crcTableComputed) {
            crcTableComputed = true;
            crcTable = [];
            var c:uint;
            for (var n:uint = 0; n < 256; n++) {
                c = n;
                for (var k:uint = 0; k < 8; k++) {
                    if (c & 1) {
                        c = uint(uint(0xedb88320) ^ 
                            uint(c >>> 1));
                    } else {
                        c = uint(c >>> 1);
                    }
                }
                crcTable[n] = c;
            }
        }
        var len:uint = 0;
        if (data != null) {
            len = data.length;
        }
        png.writeUnsignedInt(len);
        var p:uint = png.position;
        png.writeUnsignedInt(type);
        if ( data != null ) {
            png.writeBytes(data);
        }
        var e:uint = png.position;
        png.position = p;
        c = 0xffffffff;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < (e-p); i++) {
            c = uint(crcTable[
                (c ^ png.readUnsignedByte()) & 
                uint(0xff)] ^ uint(c >>> 8));
        }
        c = uint(c^uint(0xffffffff));
        png.position = e;
        png.writeUnsignedInt(c);
    }
}
}
```

I have searched through the forums here and I've noticed similar issues, but I haven't figured out how to fix this yet.  If you have any ideas, please help!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because you've made `encode()` static? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143504/flash-as3-calling-a-function-from-a-class-within-a-seperate-class).

BTW, I hope you are using this for small images, because with "no filter" the PNG will be quite large.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I tried making encode() not static, but still the same thing.  As for the large image..I guess I'll have to tackle one problem at a time, but thanks for that heads up.

Any other ideas?

Comment: btw I did not write the PNG image code myself..found the script available online.  I still have not figured this problem out yet, any ideas?